# random characters on links

Tags: links

Just recently i have noticed same set of stings appended to all my links on pages, where did this come from. if you look on the following page http://www.spectrumasa.com/services/si-time hover over the links and you will notice `?phpMyAdmin=JeyfrRdOidtd1oqamYTFrESz6u2&phpMyAdmin=c93d0493be3f8db1c43d215d9955edc9` which should not be there.

The parameters seem to only appear on page content and not posts or widgets or menu items. what more information can i give as i am not aware of any changes made.

Comment: Had you performed any database–related actions lately? This doesn't seem to be related to WordPress in any way, I would try asking hosting support.

Comment: my wordpress has not been touched for very long time, google analytics has shown these links this since July i think.

Comment: A quick Googling suggests that this problem is a result of restoring a backup created using phpMyAdmin via Plesk. It's possible that your host did it without telling you (kinda lame, but still). Like Rarst said, this is probably not a WP issue.  [Here's a discussion](http://forums.modx.com/thread/44637/solved-weird-phpmyadmin-variables-being-added-to-links-and-inputs) that might help.

Comment: i don't use plesk or phpmyadmin.